# Pioneer Navigation Setup video playback

Tags: toyota, audio, navigation

I have a Pioneer Navigation Setup and it supports only AAC, MP3 and WMV format of videos to play,

Now the problem is AAC, MP3 are working fine, but WMV i am unable to figure out how to make it work, i convert videos using any video converter still unable to load them. but there is one wmv video which is working fine with audio and video. i am trying to convert video as working video but i have no idea how to do it. i tried making the video size small, big, with audio, without audio and all the way possible, but could not get a similar video converted to play.

how can i do this and make videos to play in my setup?

This is the setup pioneer carrozzeria avic-mrz02-2
http://pioneer.jp/carrozzeria/carnavi/rakunavi/avic-mrz02-2/

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues with putting videos on SD cards on both a Kenwood and a Jensen. The answer (for me) lay in the encoding, not the wrapper (in your case, the wrapper is WVM). I had to back off from H.264 and MPEG4 down to MPEG2 in order to get videos that would play.

Discussion: Apparently licensing codecs costs money, and few people use these features. I guess most just play DVD's? Anyway when I tried to pursue it on auto A/V forums, the silence was deafening. Apparently video transcoding and auto A/V installation are not commonly overlapping competencies.